# In MySQL I need to retrieve artist with highest points by location

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In MySQL I need to get artist with highest points by location. Please help.

**user_location_tbl (user location table)**

```
|--------------------------------------|
| countryLat | countryLong  |  userid  |
|--------------------------------------|
| 31.695766  | 54.624023    |  1       |
| 20.593684  | 78.96288     |  2       |
| 20.593684  | 78.96288     |  3       |
| 20.593684  | 78.96288     |  4       |
| 31.695766  | 54.624023    |  5       |
|--------------------------------------|
```

**fans_table (to view which artist has which user as a fan)**

```
|----------------------|----------
| artist_id  | user_id |  Points |   
|----------------------|----------
| 1          | 1       |    20    |
| 1          | 2       |    30    |
| 2          | 1       |    40    |
| 2          | 3       |    40    |   
| 3          | 1       |    60    |
|----------------------|----------
```

**artist_table (list of artist)**

```
|-------------------|
| artistid | name   |
|-------------------|
| 1        | raja   | 
| 2        | sekar  |
| 3        | thomas |
|-------------------|
```

I need to get location wise which artist is having highest point but I can't do it in a single query. If I put sum(points) and group by countryLat, countryLong, artistid, I get the following result...

```
|---------------------------------|
| 100 | 20.593684 | 78.96288  | 1 |
| 50  | 20.593684 | 78.96288  | 2 |
| 100 | 31.695766 | 54.624023 | 3 |
| 90  | 31.695766 | 54.624023 | 1 |
|---------------------------------|
```

...but I only need the artist with highest point on that location as in the example below...

```
|---------------------------------|
| 100 | 20.593684 | 78.96288  | 1 |
| 100 | 31.695766 | 54.624023 | 3 |
|---------------------------------|
```

SQL

```
SELECT Sum(c.tot_points), 
       a.artist_id 
FROM   `fans_table` AS a 
       INNER JOIN `user_location_tbl` AS b 
               ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
       INNER JOIN artist_table AS c 
               ON a.artist_id = c.id 
GROUP  BY b.countrylat, 
          b.countrylong, 
          a.artist_id
```

Above is my query

Comment: your database is called mysql, not mysqli

Comment: Who the hell is voting up. Question isn't clear at all. Where do you get points from? I only see 100 points for artist 1  and 300 for artist 3, how did you expect 100 points for both in final result? and where did you get points for result you get with your own query. Also, what have you tried. Post some sql code please

Comment: And how is the fans table relevant to this problem?

Comment: if a user is fan of artist then  artistid and userid is stored in fans table and other details like total comments to that artist might be there in that table

Comment: i need to get which artist is having highest points by location

Comment: Why are you storing latitude and longitude for countries and not the country’s name, or a foreign key to a table of countries?

Comment: I need to show that values in the google map so only i storing lat and long of countires which could be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming I understand your question right you want to get which artist has the most points for each location so this would be the process to figure it out manually:

```
// First we add up all the points for each artist in each location:
|----------------------------------------------|
| Points | countryLat | countryLong | artistid |
|----------------------------------------------|
|    30  |  20.593684 |  78.96288   |     1    |
|    40  |  20.593684 |  78.96288   |     2    |
|     0  |  20.593684 |  78.96288   |     3    |
|    20  |  31.695766 |  54.624023  |     1    |
|    40  |  31.695766 |  54.624023  |     2    |
|    60  |  31.695766 |  54.624023  |     3    |
|----------------------------------------------|

// Then we get the max for each location
|----------------------------------------------|
| Points | countryLat | countryLong | artistid |
|----------------------------------------------|
|    40  |  20.593684 |  78.96288   |     2    |
|    60  |  31.695766 |  54.624023  |     3    |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

The query to do this is as follows

```
SELECT artist_id, ul.countryLat, ul.countryLong, max_points
FROM fans_table f
JOIN user_location_tbl ul
ON ul.userid = f.user_id
JOIN (
    SELECT countryLat, countryLong, MAX(f.total_points) max_points
    FROM
        (SELECT artist_id, countryLat, countryLong, SUM(Points) as total_points
        FROM fans_table f
        JOIN user_location_tbl ul
        ON ul.userid = f.user_id
        GROUP BY artist_id, countryLat, countryLong) f
    GROUP BY countryLat, countryLong) p
ON p.countryLat = ul.countryLat
AND p.countryLong = ul.countryLong
GROUP BY f.artist_id, ul.countryLat, ul.countryLong
HAVING p.max_points = SUM(Points)
```

Answer (score 1):

Making an assumption that the points in an area will be unique (ie, either there won't be 2 equally popular artists in an area, or if there are you want them both) then something like the following will do it

```
SELECT Sub3.artist_id, Sub3.countryLat, Sub3.countryLong, Sub2.MaxArtistLocalPoints
FROM
(
    SELECT a.artist_id, countryLat, countryLong, SUM(a.Points) AS ArtistLocalPoints
    FROM `fans_table` AS a 
    INNER JOIN  `user_location_tbl` AS b ON a.user_id=b.user_id 
    INNER JOIN artist_table AS c ON a.artist_id=c.id 
    GROUP BY a.artist_id, countryLat, countryLong
) Sub3
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT countryLat, countryLong, MAX(ArtistLocalPoints) AS MaxArtistLocalPoints
    FROM
    (
        SELECT a.artist_id, countryLat, countryLong, SUM(a.Points) AS ArtistLocalPoints
        FROM `fans_table` AS a 
        INNER JOIN  `user_location_tbl` AS b ON a.user_id=b.user_id 
        INNER JOIN artist_table AS c ON a.artist_id=c.id 
        GROUP BY a.artist_id, countryLat, countryLong
    ) Sub1
) Sub2
ON Sub3.countryLat = Sub2.countryLat
AND Sub3.countryLong = Sub2.countryLong
AND Sub3.ArtistLocalPoints = Sub2.MaxArtistLocalPoints
```